# Strategy Pattern violating Liskov's substitution principle

Tags: java, c#, .net, design-patterns

I am implementing **Strategy Pattern** for implementing behaviour of different types of ducks. Here is the code:

```
public interface IFlybehaviour 
{
  public void fly();
}
public class GeneralFlybehaviour
{
  public void fly()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("I can fly as a duck");
  }
}

public abstract class Duck
{
  IFlybehaviour flybehaviour;
  Duck()
  {
  }
  public void PerformFly()
  {
   flybehaviour.fly();
  }
}

public class SimpleDuck : Duck
{
  public SimpleDuck(IFlybehaviour flybehaviour)
  {
    flybehaviour = new GeneralFlybehaviour();
  }
}

In the main method
void main()
{
  Duck d = new SimpleDuck();
  d.PerformFly();
}
```

This obeys both "**Open Closed Principle**" and "**Liskov's Substitution Principle**" where I am able to create 50 different types of ducks like `SimpleDuck`, `FlyingDuck` etc.

Now I need a class `ComplicatedDuck` where it has a special power to grant wishes of its disciples lets say:

```
//public class ComplicatedDuck extends Duck (Java)
    public class ComplicatedDuck : Duck 
    {
      public ComplicatedDuck(IFlybehaviour flybehaviour)
      {
        flybehaviour = new GeneralFlybehaviour();
      }

     public void GrantWishes()
     { 
       Console.WriteLine("Wish Granted")
     }
    }
```

With this change we know that it is violating "Liskov's Substitution principle" where this subclass will not replace its Baseclass completely.

Suppose if I add one more function in **"abstract class Duck"** then all the inherited members atleast need to provide a implementation saying that "I dont grant special wishes".

In this scenario which is the better solution , adding a method in ComplicatedDuck class or extending the BaseClass

> Note: Same concept works for Java also just replacing ":" by
>   "implements" keyword.

Comment: I can be wrong, but `ComplicatedDuck`(if it is a derived class of abstract `Duck` and has method `PerformFly`, which you missed to add) doesn't seem to be a violation of LSP, because it can fly like any other duck and you can use it by reference of base class.

Comment: Thanks. I would also suggest that you reorder your code. Start with the base interface and class. Humans read text top to bottom (at least in context of English text). So don't use names that get defined later.

Comment: @KozhevnikovDmitry : The whole point is ComplicatedDuck has GrantWishes() which is not present in BaseClass Duck and even in the other 50 Derived classes like SimpleDuck etc.

Comment: `public SimpleDuck(IFlybehaviour flybehaviour){flybehaviour = new GeneralFlybehaviour();}` - you pass parameter, assign it something else and do not use it anywhere. It does not make sense. What did you try to do?

Comment: @user1400915, right, however it doesn't violate LSP. At least in context you provided. Adding `GrantWiches` to base class is not a good idea. It looks like violation of SRP. Better look on Bridge pattern an implement kinda `IWishGranter`.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek : Can you see the BaseClass Implementation there is a method called  PerformFly().

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of [composition vs inheritance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

You create a base class car... All your foreseeable cars have doors and wheels, and an engine of some description... inheritance is working well...  yet radios are optional. what do you do. well you use composition.

You create an Interface called IRadio, and for each car that has a radio, you decorate it with IRadio (assuming this is C#), this is composition. Its easy to check if a car has a radio, just check for IRadio, its easy to turn on the radio in any car that has one, RadioEnabled.

The take home part. Forcing methods on derived classes that dont need them is messy. Yet making everything composible when it could be derviable is also a waste. you need to just draw the line logically

Comment: Just a clarification , if a car has implemented IRadio which is composition , is it still considered to obey the "Liskov principle"? In my understanding the Derived class needs to be completely substitutible being its properties or Methods.

Comment: IMO it does because *Child classes never break the parent class type definitions* **and** *Subtypes are substitutable for their base types.*

Answer (score 0):

The strategy pattern is about having different implementations for `IFlyBehavior` and not about having inherited classes for `Duck`.

One issue with your code is that you have a private field in your `Duck` base class that is never used. It can only be used by Duck, so all inheriting types can not access it. If you `PerformFly()` you will get a NullReferenceException - always. If you want to inherit `Duck` would probably want to take the IFlyBehavior in the Duck's constructor.

Also

```
flybehaviour = new GeneralFlybehaviour();
```

kind of defeats the purpose of having the strategy pattern as it forces a specific implementation on it. I suppose that instead of inheriting from Duck you would use composition if you want to use a specific `IFlyBehavior` implementation

Answer (score -4):

I think you just missed inheriting ComplicatedDuck from Duck class. It has to be like - 
ComplicatedDuck : Duck

- You can move existing method - public void GrantWishes() to abstract class Duck.
- Make it virtual with empty definition.
- In ComplicatedDuck class override the behaviour as you need.
- Do nothing in SimpleDuck class.

that way substitution principle is not violated.